# Accessing parent class attribute from sub-class body

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class `Klass` with a class attribute `my_list`. I have a subclass of it `SubKlass`, in which i want to have a class attribute `my_list` which is a modified version of the same attribute from parent class:

```
class Klass():
    my_list = [1, 2, 3]


class SubKlass(Klass):
    my_list = Klass.my_list + [4, 5] # this works, but i must specify parent class explicitly
    #my_list = super().my_list + [4, 5] # SystemError: super(): __class__ cell not found
    #my_list = my_list + [4, 5] # NameError: name 'my_list' is not defined 


print(Klass.my_list)
print(SubKlass.my_list)
```

So, is there a way to access parent class attribute without specifying its name?

**UPDATE:**

There is a bug on Python issue tracker: http://bugs.python.org/issue11339 . Let's hope it will be [solved](http://ericsnowcurrently.blogspot.com/2013/12/goals-for-python-35.html) at some point.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't.

A class definition works in Python works as follows.

1. The interpreter sees a `class` statement followed by a block of code.
2. It creates a new namespace and executes that code in the namespace.
3. It calls the `type` builtin with the resulting namespace, the class name, the base classes, and the metaclass (if applicable).
4. It assigns the result to the name of the class.

While running the code inside the class definition, you don't know what the base classes are, so you can't get their attributes.

What you *can* do is modify the class immediately after defining it.

---

EDIT: here's a little class decorator that you can use to update the attribute. The idea is that you give it a name and a function. It looks through all the base classes of your class, and gets their attributes with that name. Then it calls the function with the list of values inherited from the base class and the value you defined in the subclass. The result of this call is bound to the name.

Code might make more sense:

```
>>> def inherit_attribute(name, f):
...     def decorator(cls):
...             old_value = getattr(cls, name)
...             new_value = f([getattr(base, name) for base in cls.__bases__], old_value)
...             setattr(cls, name, new_value)
...             return cls
...     return decorator
... 
>>> def update_x(base_values, my_value):
...    return sum(base_values + [my_value], tuple())
... 
>>> class Foo: x = (1,)
... 
>>> @inherit_attribute('x', update_x)
... class Bar(Foo): x = (2,)
... 
>>> Bar.x
(1, 2)
```

The idea is that you define `x` to be `(2,)` in `Bar`. The decorator will then go and look through the subclasses of `Bar`, find all their `x`s, and call `update_x` with them. So it will call

```
update_x([(1,)], (2,))
```

It combines them by concatenating them, then binds that back to `x` again. Does that make sense?

Comment: Note that metaclasses hijack #3, and can even modify `bases` before passing it on to `type`. So yeah, you can't.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I thought of that myself (via metaclasses), but extending an inherited list was just an example. One might want to delete some items from the list instead of extending it. Or have not a list but other type... Thanks for the extensive answer!

Comment: @warwaruk well the idea is that you can write your own `update_x` to do any of those things. Oh, and Ruby does let you reference classes within the class definition. But then it looks like Perl, so it's not all good! =p

Comment: @warwaruk for example, `def update_x(base_values, _): out = base_values[0]; out.pop(0); return out`. Or, I don't know, set intersection: `def update_x(base_values, my_value): return set.union(*base_values).intersection(my_value)`. Or anything.

Answer (score 3):

As answered by @katrielalex, `my_list` is not in the namespace by default *before* the class has been created.  What you could do however in Python 3, if you want to dive into metaclasses, is to add `my_list` to the namespace manually:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __prepare__(name, bases, **kwds):
        print("preparing {}".format(name), kwds)
        my_list = []
        for b in bases:
            if hasattr(b, 'my_list'):
                my_list.extend(b.my_list)
        return {'my_list': my_list}

class A(metaclass=Meta):
    my_list = ["a"]

class B(A):
    my_list.append(2)

print(A().my_list)
print(B().my_list)
```

Note that this example probably does not yet handle diamond-shaped inheritance structures well.

The new `__prepare__` attribute is defined in [PEP 3115](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a metaclass or a class decorator. Here's how you would use a metaclass in Python 2.x:

```
class Klass(object):
    my_list = [1, 2, 3]

class KlassMeta(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        # grab last base class, which in this case is Klass
        attrs['my_list'] = bases[-1].my_list + [4, 5]
        return super(KlassMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class SubKlass(Klass):
    __metaclass__ = KlassMeta
```

With Python 3 you'd declare the metaclass using the newer syntax:

```
class SubKlass(Klass, metaclass=KlassMeta):
    pass
```

Comment: Please do not encourage people to needlessly use metaclasses.They are complicated and should be avoided 9 out of 10 times anyone thinks they need one.  Most people do _not_ need to know how metaclasses work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way from the body of the class; from a context in which self is available (or the class itself), you can examine `__bases__`.

Comment: No, `self` is not available. Otherwise i could have used `super()`

Answer (score -1):

As you've seen from the other responses such as katriealex's: No, you can't.  At least not easily.

Q: What are you actually trying to do?

Q: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Python has a nice feature which Alex Martelli calls 'data inheritance'. In `__init__` i can write `self.setting1 = self.setting1 + 5`, where `setting1` is a class attribute. It might be even parent class attribute. In the latter example i haven't used any special code, the lookup by name in the class attributes is done automatically. I want the same feature within class body.

Comment: @warvariuc that is going to create an instance attribute called `self.setting1`, which is then going to accessed in front of any class attribute. So although that's going to help in some circumstances, it's not going to let people set class attributes...