# Setting a baseclass class attribute dynamically from within parent class __bases__ attribute

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python, and wondering if I'm doing something that may cause trouble down the line (or have gone about this in completely the wrong way); setting a class attribute of a common inherited bases classes from within a parent `__bases__` attribute ...

To explain: I have half a dozen derived classes (A, B, C...) all inheriting a base class called LevelMixin.

```
class A(LevelMixin):
....

class B(LevelMixin):
....

class C(LevelMixin):
....


class LevelMixin(object):
"""Contains all schema meta-info for a particular level"""

_unpickleable = False

def __getstate__(self):

    if LevelMixin._unpickleable:
         # modify state to hide private instance attributes
    else:
        state = self.__dict__.copy()
```

The derived classes are instantiated in a nested structure, such that properties on A are instances of B and so on:

```
a=A(b=B(c=C(d=D())))
```

When it's time to pickle an instance of A, I want all the classes that subclass LevelMixin to have access to the same "unpickleable" attribute (so i can set it once rather than pass it down through the code as each class is instantiated). e.g, a._unpickleable=True, a.b._unpickleable=True, a.b.c._unpickleable=True

To this end, I've accessed the LevelMixin class attribute dynamically by:

```
    if unpickleable:    # override the Level class attribute
        A.__bases__[0]._unpickleable = True
    else:
        A.__bases__[0]._unpickleable = False

    schema.append(
        A(
            b=B(
                ...)
        )
    )
```

but this feels hacky. A similar approach has been suggested for the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760595/accessing-parent-class-attribute-from-sub-class-body), but is this the right way to go?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: the answer you referred to was trying to modify/access the base class attribute in subclass at time of instantiation of subclass. is this what you want? also, how do you mean by "I want all the baseclass to have access to the same attribute"? all the baseclass?

Comment: @stucash I've updated the question to be clearer (I hope) :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where the code in your last block is located, but I'd think just naming `LevelMixin` would be better than the `__bases__` hackiness. That's where you're looking it up in `LevelMixin.__getstate__`, so there's nothing dynamic to where the assignment needs to go. That overrides the value for *all* instances, not just the ones in a single hierarchy, but that seems to be what you want.

Comment: @Blckknght ah ok, so is it not possible to have an instance of A (a=A(b=B(...)) to have all LevelMixin.unpickleable = True, and another instance of A to have all LevelMixin.unpickleable = False without manually passing unpickleable as a named attribute (e.g., a=A(unpickleable=True, b=B(unpickleable=True...))) ? Is there anyway to achieve this via scoping?Could i wrap each in a function?

Comment: @Liz thanks. But I think you need to at least show us the `__init__` of your classes (base and derived). with your codes shared here, your nested instantiation is not valid and giving errors. we are getting there, no worries. one more thing could you also update this line "I want **all the classes that subclass LevelMixin** to have access to the same "unpickleable" attribute" sorry being pedantic here but I think it's good for all of us, thanks a lot :)

Comment: you can think about your nested syntax here. it means your constructor(`__init__` in python) takes in exactly one argument which is also a instance of, probably `LevelMixin`? (i.e. the base class). then it becomes endless doesn't it? you will have to pass in one more `LevelMixin` to satisfy your constructor, but every time you pass in one more `LevelMixin` subclass, you will need to pass another one, more.

Comment: And if you could clarify your usecase of `pickle` it'll be great. in python, `pickling` and `unpickling` have [specific meanings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), i.e. `serialisation` and `deserialisation`. if you actually mean this, please could you use them instead because that'll help others understand your intention better as well. thanks very much!

Comment: @Liz re. your comment to Blckknght, if you don't tell python interpreter in any way that you want `A1.unpickable = True` and `A2.unpickable = False`, then you have to tell python how to work out right?