# Using class variables from superclass to initialize class variables in subclass without super()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I want to use a class variable in my parent class for initializing a class variable in a child class. I think I have found a solution that uses super():

```
class Parent:
    PARENT_CLASS_VAR = 'ABC'

class Child(Parent):
    CHILD_CLASS_VAR = super().PARENT_CLASS_VAR
```

However, I'm curious whether this is a good way to do this and whether there are other ways.

EDIT: Meanwhile, I've also thought that another valid solution is using the `__init__` constructor and calling the superclass class variable using `self`.

Comment: Given that this `super()` call throws an exception, I would say no, this is not a good way to do this...

Comment: By the way, your child class doesn't inherit from the parent class. Typo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing parent class attribute from sub-class body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760595/accessing-parent-class-attribute-from-sub-class-body)

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, Child should have inherited from Parent (corrected now). So, as far as I've read in the other topic you mentioned, it's not possible unless you do some tricks (like metaclasses, whatever those are :D)